# Downloading maven metadata connection refused causing slow build

Tags: maven-3

I'm using maven 3.1.1 and am working on a big Java project in which we have a large number of dependencies on different components of the Spring Framework. Whenever I build via `mvn clean install` the build takes forever. I've looked at the terminal, and essentially the build takes long because maven is trying to download metadata from a source from which it can't establish a connection:

It basically blocks here:

```
Downloading: http://source.mysema.com/maven2/releases/org/springframework/spring-beans/maven-metadata.xml
```

After a while, I'll get a connection refused before the client can even proceed any further. I have no such direct dependency from source.mysema.com so I'm not exactly sure why maven would even attempt to download from here.

A few questions:

1) How does metadata actaully work? When does maven actually attempt to pull this information? Does metadata exist for every dependency, or is this repository-specific?

2) Is there a way to force a timeout on the client to not pull this metadata if it can't establish a connection after let's say, 2 seconds?

3) I've looked into our own internal repository in which this project depends via the `<repository>` tag. In trying to debug this issue, I've looked directly at our Nexus repository and saw that the metadata.xml file contains a huge list of versions for this specific Spring dependency. Why should my build always download ALL the versions for this dependency?

My suspicion was that my `repository` definitions in my pom.xml was causing maven to download from that source.mysema.com transitively (via some remote repository I've definied). So I commented out all my `repository` definitions in hopes that maven wouldn't talk to any remote repositories and instead pull out dependencies from my local m2, but somehow it keeps trying to download from source.mysema.com.

Thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a repository manager? This does not look like this...

Comment: A repository manager like Nexus? My team isn't directly using one, but our organization is. We're depending on them in an opaque way (we don't know how they've set it up other than the fact that they host some in-house and third-party dependencies)

Comment: Use a repository either use the corporate one or setup a second a proxy to your corporate one. Furthermore clean up your infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your questions

1) How does metadata actaully work? When does maven actually attempt to pull this information? Does metadata exist for every dependency, or is this repository-specific?

Answer : maven-metadata is downloaded since you have specified Release into one of your version tags for eg

```
<spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
```

So now with daily build, you will see the metadata being downloaded as maven checks for latest build versions for this release. You will be seeing something like this in your screen

Downloading: http://nexus.mynexuslocation/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/springframework/spring-tx/maven-metadata.xml

Downloading: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-tx/maven-metadata.xml

Also check the updatePolicy in your pom.xml if it is has been set to daily

2) Is there a way to force a timeout on the client to not pull this metadata if it can't establish a connection after let's say, 2 seconds?

Answer : Not sure of this one.

3) I've looked into our own internal repository in which this project depends via the  tag. In trying to debug this issue, I've looked directly at our Nexus repository and saw that the metadata.xml file contains a huge list of versions for this specific Spring dependency. Why should my build always download ALL the versions for this dependency?

Answer : You have to move nexus repository up in the hierarchy. Maven will look at nexus first and only when not able to find it, will go outside nexus.